# Use SubtleCrypto (or other browser API) to sign Google JWT

Tags: google-chrome, google-cloud-platform, oauth, jwt, cryptography

I'm currently writing a Chrome extension, which will get an access token from Google OAuth via a service account. I have basically everything ready, except I am stuck on signing the JWT. I have looked over countless other answers, but none of the suits my need, as they

- are NodeJS based
- utilise a library that I CANNOT import into a chrome extension(e.g. is module-based or without browser support)
- are not about signing, but about decoding/verifying a Google JWT for OAuth purposes
- show code samples for signing OTHER JWT's, whose key and format don't exactly match my need
- are not even Javascript, but Python or Java or something.

After some digging, currently this is the code I have :

```
function base64ToArrayBuffer(b64) {
    var byteString = atob(b64)
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteString.length)
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        byteArray[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i)
    }

    return byteArray
}

async function encodeJWT(email, scopes, key) {
    let iat = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000)
    let exp = iat + Math.floor((60 * 60 * 1000) / 1000)
    let claims = {
        iss: email,
        scope: scopes.join(' '),
        aud: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
        exp: exp,
        iat: iat
    }

    let JWT_header = btoa(JSON.stringify({ alg: 'RS256', typ: 'JWT' }))
    let JWT_claimset = btoa(JSON.stringify(claims))
    let unsignedJWT = [JWT_header, JWT_claimset].join('.')

    key = key.replace('-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----', '').replace('-----END PUBLIC KEY-----', '').replace(/\n/g, '')
    let importedKey = await crypto.subtle.importKey('pkcs8', base64ToArrayBuffer(key), {
        name: 'RSA-OAEP',
        hash: {
            name: 'SHA-256'
        }
    }, true, ['sign'])
    let JWT_signature = await crypto.subtle.sign({
        name: 'RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5',
        hash: {
            name: 'SHA-256'
        }
    }, importedKey, new TextEncoder().encode(unsignedJWT))

    return [unsignedJWT, new TextDecoder().decode(new Uint8Array(JWT_signature))].join('.')
}
```

The problem is with the signing part. Whatever I do, I cannot seem to have the key in the right format, there are too many error messages, and if I tweak one thing, it'll tell me another thing is not in the right format or some DataError. Most of the times these error messages are not helpful at all.

The email is just the email of the service account, and the key is private key inside of the JSON that comes with the account, a string in the format of

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nXXXX...XXX\nXXXX..XXX\n...\n-----END PUBLIC KEY----- (middle is omitted)
```

Could someone tell me

1. Is it possible to sign a Google JWT with SubtleCrypto or any other non-node, but broswer API that I can run in a chrome extension environment(which is basically like an HTML environment without the DOM API)?
2. If yes, could someone point me at the right direction? How should I go about signing the JWT?

Comment: As a side note, it seems that the official Google OAuth library is also built for npm, thus I cannot use it in my browser extension. Webpack exists, but so far I am not considering it. Since OAuth REST API exists, the only problem left here is signing the JWT

Comment: You cannot use an RSA public key to sign a JWT. I recommend learning how to create a signed JWT (assertion) and how to exchange the assertion for an access token outside the browser. I have written articles on the process and there are code examples on Stack Overflow. Tip: do not remove the RSA key headers. They are required to know the data encoding format.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks, but I am looking for a in-browser solution. Any recommendations on that ?

Comment: Signing is always done with the private key, not the public key. RS256 applies RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 (which WebCrypto also supports). For key import and signing the *same* padding variant must be specified (OAEP is a variant used for encryption). JWT applies Base64url (not Base64). The signature must be Base64url encoded (not UTF-8 decoded) for concatenation.